# dynamically assign environment variable upon if condition on another variable

Tags: if-statement, github, variables, github-actions, workflow

If the variable ENVIRONMENT is either `dev` or `qa` then I wish to  have a new environment variable `FINALENV` set to `nonprod` else to `prod`

Below is my workflow file from a `develop` [non-master] branch

I face 2 problems with my workflow.

1. I do not get the `Run Workflow` button to trigger the workflow manually.
2. I expected `FINALENV` to print as `non-prod` as the `if` condition was met however it prints `blank`.

I'm new to github workflows. Kindly suggest.

```
---

name: CICD-RECYCLE

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "*"

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "*"

  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      ENVIRONMENT:
        type: choice
        options:
          - dev
          - qa
          - perf
          - uat
          - prod

jobs:

  SETVARS:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
 
      - name: Print environment variable
        run: |
          echo "ENV is ${{ env.ENVIRONMENT }} only."         

    
      - name: Set environment variable for nonprod ENV
        run: |
          echo "FINALENV=nonprod"  >> $GITHUB_ENV
        if: ${{env.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' || env.ENVIRONMENT == 'qa'}}

      - name: Set environment variable for prod ENV
        run: |
          echo "FINALENV=prod"  >> $GITHUB_ENV
        if:  ${{env.ENVIRONMENT != 'dev' || env.ENVIRONMENT != 'qa'}}

      - name: Print environment variable for ENV
        run: |
          echo "FINALENV is ${{ env.FINALENV }} only."
```

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your workflow. Please use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ and fix all those.

Comment: Refer to [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) for detailed description of the elements in your workflow..

Comment: @Azeem sorry I messed up while pasting the workflow code. I have corrected the same however, the issue persists.

Comment: What kind of runner is it i.e. `1561`?

Comment: @Azeem its a Windows server 2019 runner. You may choose to change it to anything else.

Comment: With Windows runner, you're using Bash syntax throughout your `run` sections but the default on Windows runner is `pwsh`. It should be `shell: bash` if that is intended. Wherever you use `env.ENVIRONMENT`, it should be `inputs.ENVIRONMENT`. Also, from the job name i.e. `SETVARS`, it seems like you're using it to set env vars and most probably want to use these in your next jobs. That won't work as each job runs in a different runner. So, you need to change your strategy here.

Comment: It could all be simplified to [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJx1UF1PwjAUfd+vOCGE6sP4AUsgwTl1CU4DSOITKazLprUtawcxwH+329xgBl/a+3HuPfccQb+YBz/0791Z4L/708BxpPAcQBU6rX/OVznbFkybMt/L/DPhcr+KM62o2VQgIBOqMLqOgSBahrOX6DmIFk0JMN/Kcm1SmW1YW5TKZFLoMwpwEbNdJ9/STqpYnnQKBTVdQC5jx/mQ62rvPFgsJ7N5TZEXQrtWIYhmPHFTqQ2LSdWqnpgltOBnJRZ/vk2njHMPa6pTpyraYdVCXYjKzTkzeAijydS60I4ysbvU2PQ99A8H3NTuDS9sw2gEYn0gOB7xT3tLyS0GAxAhRSm5wpI6Op1atlICmPUdvYZ21G+iHsZj9B/DxdPb3ao8+I+Y1zwTV+Rc2YlMo1077P0CfwDWwpwI). Change `self-hosted` to `1561`.

Comment: @Azeem correct the `runs_on`

Comment: Not in the question. :) Here in [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJx1UF1PwjAUfd+vOCGE6sP4AUsgwTl1CU4DSOITKazLprUtawcxwH+329xgBl/a+3HuPfccQb+YBz/0791Z4L/708BxpPAcQBU6rX/OVznbFkybMt/L/DPhcr+KM62o2VQgIBOqMLqOgSBahrOX6DmIFk0JMN/Kcm1SmW1YW5TKZFLoMwpwEbNdJ9/STqpYnnQKBTVdQC5jx/mQ62rvPFgsJ7N5TZEXQrtWIYhmPHFTqQ2LSdWqnpgltOBnJRZ/vk2njHMPa6pTpyraYdVCXYjKzTkzeAijydS60I4ysbvU2PQ99A8H3NTuDS9sw2gEYn0gOB7xT3tLyS0GAxAhRSm5wpI6Op1atlICmPUdvYZ21G+iHsZj9B/DxdPb3ao8+I+Y1zwTV+Rc2YlMo1077P0CfwDWwpwI). I used `self-hosted`, you can change it back to `1561` for your testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows runner, you're using Bash syntax throughout in your `run` sections but the default shell on Windows runner is `pwsh`. It should be `shell: bash` if that is intended.

See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for more details.

---

Wherever you use `env.ENVIRONMENT`, it should be `inputs.ENVIRONMENT`.

Also, from the job name i.e. `SETVARS`, it seems like you're using it to set env vars only and most probably want to use these in your next jobs. That won't work as each job runs in a different runner. So, you need to change your strategy here.

Your current workflow may be simplified to this:

```yaml
name: CICD-RECYCLE

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ENVIRONMENT:
        type: choice
        options:
          - dev
          - qa
          - perf
          - uat
          - prod

jobs:
  SETVARS:
    runs-on: '1561'
    
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: Set FINALENV
        env:
          FINALENV: ${{ (inputs.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' || inputs.ENVIRONMENT == 'qa') && 'nonprod' || 'prod' }}
        run: echo "FINALENV=$FINALENV" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: Print FINALENV
        run: echo "FINALENV is $FINALENV."
```

Depending on your use case, you might need to perform above steps only if it's a `workflow_dispatch` event:

```
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
```

Comment: how will i be able to access this variable `FINALENV` in another job?

Comment: @Ashar: That's a completely different issue and has already been answered in other SO threads. It cannot be done with the env vars. You need the output parameters to share such values between jobs. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.